# Some GUI for mklink?

Tags: windows, hardlink, symlink, junction

Do you know some GUI tool to create Hardlinks/SoftLinks/Junctions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you will find a more feature-rich and well-documented utility/add-on than  Hermann Schinagl's Link Shell Extensions found here: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html

Truly everthing else that I have read and used pales by comparison.

Answer (score 3):

[NTFS Link](http://elsdoerfer.name/=ntfslink) provides an explorer extension for creating hard links.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Junction link magic](http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [symlinker](http://code.google.com/p/symlinker/).

I haven't found a shell extension to create symbolic links yet (NTFS Link, suggested by Adam, can only create hard links and doesn't have x64 shell support).

Answer (score 1):

I've used symlinker as well. It's simple if you have a slight understanding of the differences between varying symlinks. It doesn't however scan for symlinks, but I really don't need that function anyway.